# How to write a Celery group or chain using transaction.on_commit

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am using django 3.0.2, python 3.6.6, celery 4.3.0, and redis server 4.0.9. I want to create some chains and groups of tasks that run after the model has been saved (transaction.on_commit). I can make an individual task work this way, but I can't seem to devine the correct incantation to make a group or chain use transaction.on_commit.

Sidebar: I extended the celery Task class to "hide" the lamba stuff when using transaction.on_commit because I always had to look up the correct format - see [https://browniebroke.com/making-celery-work-nicely-with-django-transactions](https://browniebroke.com/making-celery-work-nicely-with-django-transactions/)/ for the details. In my code, I use task.delay_on_commit to replace the transaction.on_commit and lambda.

Back to the main story. I tried this code, and it failed saying the the object query in my tasks did not exist.

```
jobs = group(tasks.clean_document_image.delay_on_commit(self.document_id, key, values[key]) for key in values).apply_async()
```

clean_document_image takes an uploaded image (the document_id object's FileField) and creates several copies of the image in different sizes (the key in the values dictionary is the width of the copy, and the value in the values dictionary is just the string name of the size - e.g., thumb, xsmall, xxxlarge, etc.). Notice that I tried to delay each of the elements of the group until the transaction saving the FileField compeleted.

When I run this "emulation" of a group, it works as expected, the object with the FileField has been saved and the lookup with the document_i works.

```
for key in values:
    tasks.clean_document_image.delay_on_commit(self.document_id, key, values[key])
```

What is the rght way to create a group of tasks that don't start until the django object has been saved? In other words, how do I incorporate transaction.on_commit into a group of tasks?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this works:

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.on_commit(lambda: chain(task1.si(args), 
                                    task2.si(args), 
                                    task3.si(args)).delay())
```

The .si is for tasks that do not return a value as input for the next task in the chain. If you want the output of task1 to be used by task2, then use task1.s(args). The first argument for task2 has to be the output value of task1.

Comment: Have you tried testing the tasks using captureOnCommitCallbacks?